# Print all links derived from a text

Tags: bash, shell

in this text file there are some links. I am trying to create a script that allows me to print all links (I have put all links in bold for you to understand).
The output should be all links below one another.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

```
tipo_evento,data_inizio,data_fine,ora_inizio,ora_fine,tutto_il_giorno,data_inserimento,autore,classe_desc,gruppo_desc,nota,aula,tipo,materia
Nota Agenda,2020-11-03,2020-11-04,,,SI,2020-10-30 12:33:25,,,,Esercitarsi con la parte pratica del libro da pag 25 a pag 28,-,compiti,SISTEMI E RETI
Nota Agenda,2020-11-03,2020-11-03,08:00:00,09:00:00,NO,2020-11-03 08:01:31,DE  ,,,**https://example.example.com/orx-aadf-dgd** ,-,nota
Nota Agenda,2020-11-03,2020-11-03,09:00:00,10:00:00,NO,2020-11-03 08:56:01, ,,,Pag 53, write an article and deliver it on classroom by 20:00 PM **https://example.example.com/afb-iddr-dmj** ,-,nota
Nota Agenda,2020-11-03,2020-11-03,10:00:00,11:00:00,NO,2020-11-03 10:04:12, ,4DINF,,LetteraturaGalileo Galilei: studiareDa pag. 90 a pag.96                                                                           **https://example.example.com/sbf-hpmh-ybd** pag.104  più lettura pag. 105 e analisi delmtesto pag.108Pag.110Da pag.114 a pag116 più lettura pag.121 e nalisi del testo pag. 124 e schema pag  142L'lluminismo: studiare pag. :00:00,NO,2020-11-03 09:48:31, ,4DINF,,Interrogazione , ,  e  da pag 74 a pag.94 bene pag. 92-93 -94 più powerpointStudiare da pag . 108 a pag. 119Fare esercizo pag. 97 n3 e pag.122 n 3,-,compiti,STORIA
Nota Agenda,2020-11-03,2020-11-03,12:00:00,14:00:00,NO,2020-10-29 08:46:23, ,,,**https://example.example.com/usg-iurq-udq** ,-,nota
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to show your script and we can help you.

You can use something like:

```
grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*"  file
```

Result:

```
https://meet.google.com/orx-aadf-dgd
https://meet.google.com/afb-iddr-dmj
https://meet.google.com/sbf-hpmh-ybd
https://meet.google.com/usg-iurq-udq
```

Comment: With `grep -E` you can simply use `https?:` to match with or without the `s`.