# How to Extract a particular string in a file using shell-script

Tags: bash, shell

How do I extract only the string "blade*****demandware.net" from these lines which are present in separate files using shell script and the count of the extracted number of strings on a particular date?

```
/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/jobs-blade1-7.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201026.log'
/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ETCreateSubscriberDEServi-blade9-8.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201023.log
/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/service-ACI_GC_BalanceEnquiry-blade9-9.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201026.log
/on/demandware.servlet/webdav/Sites/Logs/sysevent-blade9-8.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20201025.log
```

In real, there will be hundreds of files.

This is the script I'm using so far

```
#!/bin/bash +x
pwd
grep -ic blade *
cat *.p > test.txt
awk -F 'jobs-' '{print $2}' test.txt
```

I'm able to get some info but not the exact one I want.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64664717/print-all-links-derived-from-a-text/64664841#64664841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk:

```
 awk '{ match($0,/[0-9]{8}/);arr[substr($o,RSTART,RLENGTH)]+=1;match($0,/blade/);spoint=RSTART+RLENGTH;match($0,/\.demandware/); print substr($0,spoint,RSTART-spoint+1) } END { for (i in arr) { print i" - "arr[i]} } ' file
```

First check each line for a pattern match of date (8 numbers) create an array arr with the date as the index and increment the value. Then extract matches for blade and demand, using RSTART and RLENGTH to find the string in between. Print this string using substr. In the END block, we print the count of the matches stored in arr.

Comment: I2
1-8.mon.
p7
I5
7-2.mon.
p7
I2
9-5.mon.
p7
I8
2-4.mon.
p7
I1
4-2.mon.
p7
I3
6-6.mon.
p7
I3
2-3.mon.
p7
I2
9-9.mon.
p7
I4
1-7.mon.
p7
I4
9-8.mon.
p7
I1
3-8.mon.
p8
I8
4-2.mon.
p8
I6
3-9.mon.
p8
I1
3-2.mon.
p8
I3
1-7.mon.
p8
I2
9-9.mon.
p8
I3
9-8.mon.
p8
I4
6-5.mon.
p8
I4
6-2.mon.
p8
I2
20201028 - 19
 - 138
20201023 - 2
20201025 - 10
20201026 - 17
20201027 - 13

This is what I'm getting as output. Is there any way that we can get rid of other stuff except the last dates and count.

Comment: 20201028 - 19
 - 138
20201023 - 2
20201025 - 10
20201026 - 17
20201027 - 13

this is what I'm getting.
can we get like as mentioned below ?


20201023 - 2
20201025 - 10
20201026 - 17
20201027 - 13
20201028 - 19

Comment: Hello, I'm also getting irrelevant data apart from Date like this.

11318021 - 1
12466176 - 1
16811920 - 1
12701095 - 1
10395314 - 1
12919484 - 1
12855842 - 1
17846099 - 1
17133731 - 1
12095114 - 1
17762405 - 1
46636195 - 1
17760074 - 1
10640406 - 1
11744542 - 1
11511763 - 1
18552696 - 1
16876424 - 1

could you pls help in this. Thanks.